# Check whether a moment is valid in a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm using moment-timezone. I receive datetimestrings(iso 8601) and timezones (strings recognised as timezones by moment-timezone) and need to check whether the date is valid in the timezone. In other words, if timezone is `CET`:

- `2015-03-03T12:00:00+01:00 --> true` (is CET)
- `2015-03-03T12:00:00+02:00 --> false` (+02:00 is only CET during DST, and 3-3 is not DST)
- `2015-07-03T12:00:00+01:00 --> false`
- `2015-07-03T12:00:00+02:00 --> true`

Note, the following are both valid (and should be recognised that way), since that day DST ends.

- `2015-10-25T02:30:00+01:00 --> true`
- `2015-10-25T02:30:00+02:00 --> true`

My current approach is to convert the moment-object to the required timezone, and check if the timezone offset is the same, but I feel there should be an easier way...

```
function isValidInTimezone(date, timezone) {
  return date.format("Z") === date.clone().tz(timezone).format("Z");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function isValidInTimeZone(dateString, timeZone) {
  var m = moment.parseZone(dateString);
  return m.utcOffset() === m.tz(timeZone).utcOffset();
}
```

The `timeZone` parameter should be a full zone id, such as `"Europe/Paris"`.  Some abbreviations may work, but only the ones explicitly established for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, indeed making sure to use the `parseZone` is essential! At least `CET` works as zone. Can you confirm that all timezones are "current (ie. 2015) time zones? I fell into the trap with `pytz`, where Europe/Amsterdam is `+00:40` and Europe/Paris `+00:09`. After research these turned out to be timezones used sometime before WWII.

Comment: Both pytz and momentjs use the same underlying IANA time zone database.  Both go through the same sets of updates.  I would suspect by the values that you were using the time zone without a specific date/time, in which pytz will show the first entry - which is often the initial LMT offset. You can get the same thing in moment-timezone with ancient values like this: `moment.tz(-10000000000000,'Europe/Paris').utcOffset()`

Comment: Ah! It all falls into place! I got these old timezones because I was using pytz the wrong (but very intuitive...) way: `datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 23, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")).isoformat()` does indeed pick the first one from the list rather than the one matching the date.... The correct call `pytz.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam").localize(datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 23)).isoformat()` does indeed return the expected result. Many thanks!